# Dynamically Remove Elements Jquery .click not Firing

Tags: jquery

I am writing a script to dynamically create and remove elements, adding the elements works fine. But the #removeText function is not firing, I assume something because it was created after the page had finished loading or something. How can I get the #removeText click function to work if it has been dynamically created?

```
var i = 0;

$('#addText').on('click', function() {
    var div = $("#addText").closest('div').attr('id');

    $("<p><input type=\"text\" id=\"text" + i + "\" placeholder=\"Type something…\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"removeText\">Remove</a></p>").appendTo('#' + div);
});

$('#removeText').on('click', function() {
    console.log(1);
});
```

Comment: if adding this more than once, can't duplicate ID. By definition they must be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `#removeText` does not exist in the DOM when you call `$("#removeText").on`, then nothing gets bound because there is nothing to bind to because it does not exist.

All is not lost.  Use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '#removeText', function () {
```

You should probably do the same with `#addText` as well.  You can delegate to elements that already exist in the DOM too.